# how to get sum of this column in sql server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server

i'm use below query for fetch my data with an ordernumber...

```
SELECT     Details.Quantity, 
           Details.OrderNumber, 
           Orders.OrderDate, 
           Products.ProductName, 
           Products.UnitPrice ,
           Details.Quantity*Products.UnitPrice as qprice
FROM       Details 
INNER JOIN Orders 
   ON Details.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber 
INNER JOIN Products 
   ON Details.ProductID = Products.ProductID
where Orders.OrderNumber='14195'
```

this query give me below result

[image]

now i want give sum of qprice column..

how can i do  this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
SELECT SUM(Details.Quantity * Products.UnitPrice) AS Amount
FROM Details 
    INNER JOIN Orders ON 
        Details.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN Products ON 
        Details.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Orders.OrderNumber = '14195'
```

If you need to have TotalAmount as an extra column to what you already have then:

```
SELECT    
    Details.Quantity, 
    Details.OrderNumber, 
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Products.ProductName,
    Products.UnitPrice,
    Details.Quantity*Products.UnitPrice as qprice,
    SUM(Details.Quantity*Products.UnitPrice) OVER() TotalAmount
FROM Details 
    INNER JOIN Orders ON 
        Details.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
    INNER JOIN Products ON 
        Details.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Orders.OrderNumber = '14195'
```

Comment: thanks but gave this error ... Column 'Details.Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @hesam salehnamadi - if you specify just one `SUM` column, it should not give you errors. If you need to keep the columns that you already have then use the second query.